# Amazon-Quicksight - Syntax for SQL Server CTE

Tags: sql-server, amazon-quicksight

I am inserting a custom SQL into QS to query my DB; the query contains a CTE and some selection from the same like below:

```
with cte as
(
    .....
)
select * 
from cte;
```

Whenever I run the query in QS, I get a syntax error.

> sourceErrorMessage: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'

Any help on the syntax or whether CTEs are supported or not by QS would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Assuming Quicksight supports CTEs, I suspect there is a prior statement which does not end in a semicolon,  try *;with* ...

Comment: Thank you for your response @JohnCappelletti.
I had tried this earlier as well, doesn't work.

Unable to find any documentation as well for it.

Comment: I faced the same issue, no matter where to place the semicolon, it complains about 'With' in my Sql server script. The workaround is to use subquery instead.

Comment: I cannot even create SQL Server temporary table in my custom queries using Select Into, or Create table #tempTable.